# Would it be faster to preload my sprite image from html rather than css?

Tags: html, css, performance

It seems to me that if the only reference to my sprite image is in the css, then those two files can't be downloaded in parallel. First it would have to download the css file, THEN it would know it needed the sprites file, and it could begin to download the sprites. Would it be faster to include a little inline css that referenced the sprite image so that the two could be fetched in parallel?

Comment: While it may technically be slightly faster, unless your CSS file is huge I can't see it making a noticeable difference.

Comment: there wont be considerable difference and both cache image

Comment: @MarkParnell, I agree it would be a subtle difference. Mostly I assume it would be delay waiting for the http handshake and connection.

Answer (score 1):

If your sprite is used using javascript, then use javascript to load your sprite that way you can ensure that nothing can be done with the sprite until it is actually loaded.

If you are using css3 to use the sprite then use either css or html.

By html I mean you can include the image on your actual html file with a width and height of 1px. This ensures that the image is loaded as well.

As far as performance goes it wouldn't really make a noticeable difference. Albeit using css3 would ensure that all users of your website would have the same experience, whereas using javascript would only get the benefit if javascript was turned on.

Comment: +1 that really make sense ... also both css and html image will cache

Comment: The sprite image is being used by CSS, not Javascript. I have found many references talking about how to preload images, my question was about what (if any) performance advantage it would (or would not) have.

Answer (score 1):

We had the same issue in a project at work, a not-so-pretty solution was to add an `img` tag with the sprite as a `src` just after the opening `body` tag.

Comment: Did you actually experiencing a noticeable difference between the image being loaded in parallel with the CSS vs. serially? Just curious. I am assuming the difference is going to be quite minute, as my CSS file is quite small.

Comment: It seemed like it was loaded instantly, that, of course, also depends on the file's size.

Answer (score 1):

If your sprite is small enough you could also use a `data URI` [(data URIs on CSS-Tricks)](http://css-tricks.com/data-uris/), but then you'll have to use one selector for the `background-image` and additional selectors for the `background-image-position`, so you wont have to include the `data URI` on every selector.